# Would it be possible/advisable to parse my user input string w regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, parsing, input

I am trying to split a string according to the following rules.

```
test1 test2 test3           => [test1, test2, test3]
test1 test2:a b test3:c d   => [test1, test2:a b, test3:c d]
test1 test2:"a b" test3:c d => [test1, test2:"a b", test3:c d]
```

I could throw more examples up, but essentially, each space separated word should be it's own entry in the resulting list, UNLESS that word comes after a colon. At that point, spaced words should be considered part of the previous word, until the next word in front of a semi colon.

I am doing this to create the initial stages of my own little search engine, and I need a way to parse the input that the user gives. I am trying to avoid forcing the user to do something like this

```
test1 test2:(a, b) test3:(c, d)
```

Although I guess that would be fine if it is more aesthetically pleasing.

I am sure this could be done w javascript regular expressions, but I honestly am terrible at them, and can't wrap my head around how they work half the time.

Could anyone give me advice on how to split my string this way, either the correct regular expression or another method that would be preferable?

Thanks!

edit :

I've already got some code that does some parsing rather than using a regexp, but it is already getting long and complicated. This question is mostly to see if a regexp is a better way to go.

edit2 :

Abandoning the reg-exp approach altogether. Salman A has come up with a wonderfully concise method that does what I want, beats the hell out of the code I had previously.

Comment: Semi related but this is a good bookmark for regex. https://regex101.com/

Comment: basically splitting by the word "test" should do the trick, no?

Comment: Regex is possible but I would rather parse it.

Comment: "test" could be anything. it was meant to be a placeholder for whatever the user puts in

Comment: @SalmanA I have already tried to write some code to parse it and it covers the more simple cases, but I was hoping an elegant reg ex would knock it out in a line or so, letting me refactor.

Comment: If, I am assuming "test" and "a" can be anything you still need something to differentiate the 2. In other words, what the expected output of `xx yy:xx zz xx:xx`? if `zz` part of `yy` or on its own?

Comment: @sebnukem, the expected output would be [xx, yy:xx zz, xx:xx]

Comment: You did specify "At that point, spaced words should be considered part of the previous word, until the next word in front of a semi colon". Nevermind.

Comment: @canon
[x, x, x:x x x, x:x x, x:x x x]

Comment: @canon yea, that's what makes it so hard to wrap my head around. A non colon term would basically be telling my engine to run a "default" search, whereas something with a colon would be searching against a specific field.

Comment: @canon I've got some parsing code already, but it is already getting complicated and handles only the simpler cases.

Comment: thank god for unit testing. I basically have been just throwing up a new test case and altering my code until it can handle it. But now Ive run into some particularly troubling cases, as in my example.

Comment: test1 and test2:"a b" should be easy to do but I think the case with no separator is hard because you want to make clear what arguments you want to pass. Could you think of test3:a, b or something like this?

Comment: I could try and work it. Do you think the reg exp is even possible, albeit probably complex?

Comment: in regex its easy if you have clear rules, structures like in xml where you have a starting and an ending tag and context inbetween. But its harder to guess whether its a parameter or some new keyword that implies another command.

Comment: I guess my point of asking weather it was possible or not, is that I'm clearly able to recognize the pattern, as are all of you. Clearly some sort of algo/reg ex is going on inside my brain that allows me to do this. If that is the case, shouldn't a reg-exp be possible?

Comment: maybe its possible ... let me think of a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I knew I should have parsed it:

```js
function parseQuery(query) {
  var tokens = query.split(/\s+/), i = 0, prev, curr;
  while (i < tokens.length - 1) {
    curr = tokens[i];
    next = tokens[i + 1];
    if (curr.indexOf(":") >= 0 && next.indexOf(":") < 0) {
      tokens.splice(i, 2, curr + " " + next);
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }
  return tokens;
}
var tests = [
    'test1',
    'test1 test2',
    'test1 test2 test3',
    'test1 test2:a b test3:c d',
    'test1 test2:a b test3:c d e',
    'test1 test2:a b test3:c d e test4:f',
], i;
for (i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
  console.log(tests[i], parseQuery(tests[i]));
}
```

```html
<!-- results pane console output; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I wondered why you deleted your first answer with the simple split and then I saw the problem with it. It took me a long time.